# GNU/Linux : who to add reply-to email address in /bin/mail command

Tags: linux, email

Currently, i am using below command to send email

> echo "Test Mail" | /bin/mail -s "Test" "recv1@abc.com" -- -f "sender1@abc.com"

how can i add reply-to email address sender2@abc.com so that if recv1 reply back, it would go to sender2.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Body" | mail -S replyto="me@source.com" -s "subject" receiver@destination.com
```

Answer (score 0):

reply-to is a header property and is passed with **-a** flag

any email  can be passed as `abc@gmail.com`  OR `'A_NAME_2_EXPOSE<abc@gmail.com>'`

```
cat path/content_file | mail 
     -s 'subject' 
     -a 'from:NAME_EXPOSED<sender_email>'    // header
     -a 'Reply-To:email_to_reply'            // header
     -a 'Content-Type: text/html'            // header
     -c 'email_cc_1 email_cc_2'              // cc = 'carbon_copy'
     -b 'email_bcc_3 email_bcc_4'            // bcc = 'blind_cc'
     'target_email_5 target_email_6'
```

alternative

```
echo 'string message' | mail ......
mail .... target_emails < path/content_file
```

Answer (score -1):

Same way as every other header.

```
{ echo "Reply-to: ...@... " ; echo "Test Mail" ; } | ...
```